# How to merge two PHP for-loop

Tags: php, for-loop, joomla, module

How do I merge two (for) in one code?

e.g first code

```
for ($i = 0, $n = count($options); $i < $n; $i ++) {}
```

and second code

```
for ($u = 'rel_article1'; $u <= 'rel_article5'; $u++)
```

here is oll code

```
<?php if ($display_poll) { ?>
<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php');?>" method="post" name="poll_vote_<?php echo $poll->id;?>" id="poll_vote_<?php echo $poll->id;?>">
<?php for ($i = 0, $n = count($options); $i < $n; $i ++) { ?>
    <label for="mod_voteid<?php echo $options[$i]->id;?>" class="<?php echo $tabclass_arr[$tabcnt].$params->get('moduleclass_sfx'); ?>" style="display:block; padding:2px;">
        <input type="radio" name="voteid" id="mod_voteid<?php echo $options[$i]->id;?>" value="<?php echo $options[$i]->id;?>" alt="<?php echo $options[$i]->id;?>" <?php echo $disabled; ?> />


    <?php echo $options[$i]->text; ?>       <?php for ($u = 'rel_article1'; $u <= 'rel_article5'; $u++) { ?>

    <a href="<?php echo $params->get($u); ?>" onClick="return popup(this, 'notes')">

    <img src="/images/stories/add.png" alt="play"></a>

     <?php 
     } ?
```

> 

I want in one poll show onle play button

now shows this

[image]

here is my xml code:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need that second `for`. You already have an index with `$i` from your first loop. (Except that it starts from 0 instead of 1, but you can easily get it working)

Remove the second for, and try this :

```
// echo $params->get($u);
echo $params->get('rel_article' . ($i + 1));
```

Comment: thank you but it not work. I remove second for  and add this but not work

Comment: @user3817984 My very bad, I forgot the parenthesis on `($i + 1)` : `echo $params->get('rel_article' . ($i + 1)); `. It should be ok now. :)

Comment: how I can add you reputation?

Comment: @user3817984 Left side of the answers. You can upvote to give 10 reputs if it helped (arrow), accept the answer that helped you most to give 15 points (green mark).